# Is it advisable to call Web Services on cellForRowAtIndexPath for large datasets?

Tags: ios, web-services, uitableview, feed

If the data set is too large and I want to show the data on a table View. What should be the best possible approach ?

**First Approach**-
I call the API in cellForRowAtIndexPath. This would make the request everytime I scroll which would mean hitting the service again and again. May be I can cache the data as well but still I think it is not the best possible approach.

**Second Approach**-
First, Save all the data locally and then show it. This would mean occupying more of the internal storage.

Which approach is better or is there any better approach available ?

Comment: download data into some local array by 20/30/40 objects, twitter alike. cell for row shouldn't download anything.

Comment: @Piyush Vaish point 1 is not a good idea , point 2 , if there is any such requirement to save data locally then you can, I would say make a different class to make api call , and save data in model.

Comment: There is no such requirement. If there is a large data set, lets say facebook feeds for example then it would take a hell lot time to download all the stuff and show and obviously memory concerns are there.

Comment: Are you using pagination on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What approach will you take depends on whether your API supports pagination or not! If the API does not support pagination then you left with no other solution then to retrieve every thing in one shot and show it in tableView.

If your API supports pagination, then you can make a call to load the first page in `ViewDidLoad` and then implement `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate to check when user scrolled to Bottom of the table/collectionView and trigger the web service to fetch next page of response. This will continue till server responds with empty array.

Here is a simple scrollViewDidScroll override which you can make use of to decide if user reached end of tableView/collectionView

```
extension ViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let bottomEdge = scrollView.contentSize.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom - scrollView.bounds.height
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= bottomEdge {
            //make a webservice call now
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating too many connections is not a good idea.

You should get all of them and show in a single page for few items.

But since there is too much data, you have 2 option. Combining them is better as a 3rd option.

1. Don’t show any data, implement a search bar, request data with search text. Now you requested a subset of the data according to search text.
2. Request a subset of data (first 20 for example) and imlement `load more` button (instead of button you can use scrollview’s delegate too) or `pagination.`

If response have image links, you should download the images in cellForRowAtIndexpath. If you start to download them before, user will wait too much.